# Docker: user namespace remapping not working although enabled for daemon

Tags: docker, namespaces, daemon

Processes in docker containers are still running under the "host's" UID although I have enabled user namespace remapping.

OS is: Ubuntu 16.04 on 4.4.0-21 with

```
> sudo docker --version
Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e
```

dockerd configuration is

```
> grep "DOCKER_OPTS" /etc/default/docker
DOCKER_OPTS="--dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 --ipv6  --userns-remap=default"
```

subordinate UID and GID mappings have been created, when I had run manually, i.e., with the above docker opts string

```
> grep "dock" /etc/sub*
/etc/subgid:dockremap:362144:65536
/etc/subuid:dockremap:362144:65536
```

However, the sub UID/GIDs got not created when I (re)started dockerd as service - but had to run it manually.

Also after restarting dockerd, all processes in containers are not in the remapped range but 1to1 that of the host, i.e., a container root process still has UID=0.

E.g., a test container running just top

```
> sudo docker run -t -i ubuntu /usr/bin/top
  ...
```

has top run by UID=0 when checked outside the container on the host

```
> ps -xaf --forest -o pid,ruid,ruser,cmd | grep top
PID  RUID RUSER    CMD
23015     0 root      |           \_ sudo docker run -t -i ubuntu /usr/bin/top
23016     0 root      |               \_ docker run -t -i ubuntu /usr/bin/top
```

Apparently, the remapping to subordinate UIDs is not working for me when running docker as a daemon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/etc/default/docker is not used when running the dockerd via systemd.

Thus any changes I did on the docker-config (after the dist-upgrade I had applied before) where not applied.

For configuring the docker daemon with Systemd see the documantation at
https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/

with the configuration drop-in file(s) going to
/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d